# How can I restart docker service using puppet...?

Tags: docker, puppet

Is there any way to restart docker service using `puppet`?
I am using `garathr/docker` module to work with docker.
I am manually copying some data to `/var/lib/docker`. So there is a need of restarting the docker service.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
service { 'docker':
  ensure    => running,
  subscribe => File['resource where you are copying some data to /var/lib/docker'],
}
```

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/metaparameter.html#subscribe

I feel like there are more subtleties here, so please let me know what else is needed here.

Comment: I am pulling docker image from docker hub. Whether docker will restart if any changes happens for images in docker hub...?

Comment: how to restart automatically if the change happening in docker hub...?

Comment: Are you pulling the docker image with puppet?